# RelaxNG validation for node with unknown structure

Tags: xml, xml-validation, relaxng

I need to build a **RelaxNG** validation schema, and I faced such problem:

I have a need to validate documents with with an `<optional>` tag inside, and this `<optional>` tag might enclose some other tags inside, and I don't know their schema, or they don't have unified one.

Simplified sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elements>
  <first>
    <name>John</name>
    <sname>Silver</sname>
  </first>
  <second>
    <phone>+123456789</phone>
    <mail>js@p.com</mail>
  </second>
  <optional>
     ...
  <optional>
</elements>
```

Here I know clearly what should be inside `<first>` and `<second>` tags, but `<optional>` may contain either text or complex node structure.

Is there something in RelaxNG to mark an element in the way, that it's internal structure will be ignored?

I am looking for something like `<anyType />` here, but actually there is no such thing as anyType.

```
<element name="optional">
  <anyType />
  <zeroOrMore>
    <attribute>
      <anyName/>
    </attribute>
  </zeroOrMore>
</element>
```

There is also a tag **`<data>`** in RelaxNG, which specifies the element content type, but I can't find proper value for its **type** attribute, to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your `optional` element like this:

```
<element name="optional">
  <ref name="any"/>
</element>
```

And define `any` like this:

```
  <define name="any">
    <zeroOrMore>
      <choice>
        <attribute>
          <anyName/>
        </attribute>
        <text/>
        <element>
            <anyName/>
            <ref name="any"/>
        </element>
      </choice>
    </zeroOrMore>
  </define>
```

You should be able to put whatever you want in `optional`. This will accept any element in any namespace whatsoever with any attributes that have any values, and whatever text between the elements.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks!
Also surrounded `<element name="optional">` with `<zeroOrMore>` to handle the situation when `<optional>` tag is absent.